# How to provide Store to Routes

Tags: react-native, redux

My understanding is that I provide the store like so:

```js
const ReduxApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)


AppRegistry.registerComponent('GPScan', () => ReduxApp);
```

In the App component, I have:

```js
<Router>
        <Scene key='root'>
          <Scene
            component={Authentication}
            hideNavBar={true}
            initial={true}
            key='Authentication'
            title='Authentication'
          />
          <Scene
            component={HomePage}
            hideNavBar={true}
            key='HomePage'
            title='Home Page'
          />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
```

How do I provide the store to those Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `<Provider>` around the top `<App>` component like that *should* be sufficient.  Since it's now an ancestor component to all other components, the store should now be accessible to any other Redux-connected component, no matter what route it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Put the router in the provider.

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Scene key='root'>
      // etc
    </Scene>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```